# How add in CC email in flows email node, i can see only To?

Tags: directus, directus-flows

How trying trigger email from flows, i can add see TO input field and i can add only in To, but i wants to add** CC,BCC also**, can anyone solve this? using linux , Directus version: 9.24.0, postgresql, directus studio app,Firefox browser